# Can't delete VBScript file after running it

Tags: vba, file-io

I'm simulating multi-threading with VBA, the code creates multiple vbs files and runs them. But i am not able to delete them after they are completed, it says "can not find script file" Here is my code:

```
' Write VBScript file to disk
sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Thread_" & agentNr & ".vbs"
intFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As intFileNum
Print #intFileNum, s
Close intFileNum
' Run VBScript file
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
wshShell.Run """" & sFileName & """"


Kill sFileName
Set wshShell = Nothing
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what the exact error message is (it isn't *really* "can not find script file", is it?) and on what line the error occurs? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: If you wait a while before kill the file? or comment it, the script runs?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
1, Yes, the error was really "can not find script file".
2, Unfortunately for 5k+ rows any wait causes seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our original code, as it's in asynchronous mode, Shell has not read the script file before you removing it.

#### Now I suggest a self-destruction mode.

As comments, we run .vbs again in an asynchronous mode, but the script file will be removed at the end of the vbscript, ie, inside the script itself. The deletion instructions are appended at the end of the VBScript to be created:

```
Sub sof20351356RunVbScript()
  Dim intFileNum As Integer
  Dim agentNr As Long
  Dim sFileName As String, s As String
  Dim wshShell

  agentNr = 5

  ' Write VBScript file to disk
  sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Thread_" & agentNr & ".vbs"
  
  '
  ' In the file, we do our job normally,
  ' at the end, we kill the vbscript inside the script itself:
  '
  s = "MyVar = 1" & vbCrLf _
    & "'... do foo bar" & vbCrLf
  
  '
  ' now add the Killing order:
  s = s _
    & "Set fso = CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")" & vbCrLf _
    & "fso.DeleteFile """ & sFileName & """" & vbCrLf

  
  intFileNum = FreeFile
  Open sFileName For Output As intFileNum
  Print #intFileNum, s
  Close intFileNum
  ' Run VBScript file
  Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  '
  ' in synchronous mode:
  'wshShell.Run """" & sFileName & """", 0, True

  '
  ' in asynchronous mode:
  wshShell.Run """" & sFileName & """", 0, False


  'Kill sFileName
  Set wshShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx

As I tested so confirmed, before a script begins to run, it's read at 100% in memory by the Shell (Windows Script Interpreter), so the file itself has no more any importance when it starts executing. As a consequence, you can even add the destruction instruction at the beginning of the VBscript, before your true job.

But cmd.exe .bat file cannot be handled as this.

Comment: True, but I guess this defeats the purpose of mock multi-threading?

Comment: Yes are blocked in VBA before the script ends... Other better method is still to be found...

Comment: I like the idea of self-destruction :-)  Have you tested it?

Comment: This worked for me, did not modify anything, only added the two rows for self-destruction. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Wow, I didn't think this would be possible, having a script delete itself, but there you go, I learned something today.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett, before a script begins to run, it's read at 100% in memory by the Shell (Windows Script interpreter), so the file itself has no more any importance when it starts executing.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to delete a script file that is currently running. That's probably what is causing your problem.

How about using the [`wshShell.Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a) method instead of [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky)? That way you can keep track of whether the VBScript is done running or not, and delay deleting the VBS file until it is done.

Proof-of-concept, not tested:

```
Dim oExec
Set oExec = wshShell.Exec("sFileName")
'Can launch more processes here...

'Now check if oExec process is done
Do While oExec.Status = 0
    'oExec process not done yet...
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
'It's done. Delete the file.
Kill sFileName
```

This is of course a simplistic example with only one process. You could launch more of them and store their handles (like `oExec`) in an array/collection/dictionary. Then periodically check all the handles in succession until they are all done running.

Comment: Jean-François Corbett, we are again blocked in VBA thread here as in synchronous mode .Run().

Comment: @jacouh You could use `DoEvents()` in the loop to allow the application to respond to other events.

Comment: @Daniel Cook, So DoEvents() instead of WScript.Sleep()?

Comment: @jacouh I might try using both. Otherwise your client will go a little crazy constantly running `DoEvents`. An approximately 100 ms delay on response should go relatively unnoticed.

Comment: Waiting for response and delaying is a no-go in my case, thanks anyway!